# Copy pivot as values

Tags: vba, copy, pivot, paste

I am trying to copy the values of my pivot table into another location:

```
Sub PivotCopy()


Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables("PivotTable2").TableRange2.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("U6")


End Sub
```

It is copying the pivot but I want only the values to be copied; any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean paste as values: [`PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) using `xlPasteValues`? Or not copying over headers, grand totals, etc?

Comment: ideally both, I just want my values from the pivot but I can live with the headers if I must

Comment: But the pastespecial does bring a compile error, so maybe I am doing sth wrong

Comment: Show us the code you're using for PasteSpecial then, along with the specific compile error.

Comment: Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables("PivotTable2").TableRange2.Copy Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("U6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: the compile error says end of statement

Comment: Those should be 2 separate lines... Also check out the [`PivotSelect` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-pivotselect-method-excel) to select `xlDataOnly` before copying.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Sub PivotCopy()

Sheets("Dashboard").PivotTables("PivotTable2").TableRange2.Copy     
Sheets("Dashboard").Range("U6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```